# Authentication with Spring-Boot-Admin and Eureka discovery

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

SBA version 2.0.1

Spring-Cloud Finchley.RELEASE

I have some services registered in Eureka. The services are Spring-Boot apps, and have their actuators secured by HTTP basic auth. The service actuators are at /actuator. The services are working and I can interact with their actuators via Postman and curl. SBA connects to Eureka and discovers the services, but they are always in a down (red) state, except for the SBA application itself, which is shown just fine as green in the SBA console, and I am able to click on it and see it's properties.

When I click on one of the service instances, I am prompted for credentials. I'm not sure what credentials to use, so I use the credentials for the service actuator. I already have these credentials in the metadata-map as shown in the docs, but I am still prompted for credentials anyway. This always results in showing the Whitelabel Error Page, with an error message like this:

> Mon Jun 25 12:40:57 CDT 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'POST' not
>   supported

Though I note the url for that error is apparently on the SBA instance intself, not the remote service. The url decodes to this: http://localhost:8080/#/instances/9207aa5fc06b/

But I see this in the log for the service, so apparently an unauthenticated request is making it to the remove service:

> [2018-06-25 12:16:54.242] - DEBUG - [http-nio-8380-exec-7]
>   [AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_DEV,8dc8165d4f77be7c,8dc8165d4f77be7c,false]
>   --- [nio-8380-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor : Written [{timestamp=Mon Jun 25 12:16:54 CDT 2018, status=401,
>   error=Unauthorized, message=Unauthorized, path=/actuator/health}] as
>   "application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json" using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@30c8681]

And this in the SBA log:

> 2018-06-25 12:39:40.884 ERROR [SERVICES_ADMIN_CONSOLE_LOCAL,,,] 20728
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception
>
> java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine

This is the root of my confusion, I'm not sure what credentials I need or even what I am authenticating to. I have provided the credentials to remote service in properties as well as in the login form, and it doesn't work.

When I click on the SBA application in the SBA console, it works as expected. So this seems to be related to authenticating to a remote actuator, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableAdminServer
public class ServiceAdmin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceAdmin.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityPermitAllConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
    }
```

SBA Config:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.info.git.mode=full
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
spring.security.user.name=actuator
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.roles=ACTUATOR

eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=10
eureka.instance.health-check-url-path=/actuator/health
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name=actuator
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password=password
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://svcregistry1.mycompany.com/eureka/,http://svcregistry2.mycompany.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was I failed to understand the docs. The eureka credentials in the metadataMap have to be provided by the monitored application at registration time. Not provided in the SBA config.

Comment: could you elaborate on "Not provided in the SBA config" ? Do you mean the credentials have to configured in SBA as well?

Comment: My configuration is as follows: security.user.name=client
security.user.password=client
endpoints.info.sensitive=false
eureka.instance.metadata-map.spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.name=${security.user.name}
eureka.instance.metadata-map.spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.password=${security.user.password}
eureka.instance.metadata-map.mangement.context.path=${management.context-path}

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this question, being as puzzled as I, to clear up this answer.

I'm having Eureka and Springboot admin server/ui in the same application

All the services that will register into eureka AND springboot admin, will need their own /actuator credentials present as metadata :

```
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name = ${endpoints.user.name} 
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password = ${endpoints.user.password}
```

This post cleared up a few things.
https://zoltanaltfatter.com/2018/05/15/spring-cloud-discovery-with-spring-boot-admin/

Comment: It's also important to point out that doing this will cause the DiscoveryClient logger to log the username and password in cleartext. You'll need some kind of logging filter to mask those values. I used the Logback %replace function with this regular expression to match the pattern: (?&lt;=user\.password\":\")(.*?)(?=\")